# Cartesian product: domain of variables in ordered pair quick question.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If I have a set $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{N}\ \mid x=y\}$.

I realize this would be a "line of dots". And I think I could rewrite this as $(y,y)$ or $(x,x)$.

And I think the both ($x$ or $y$) should $\in\mathbb{N}$. Is this correct?

And the result would be this? (Yes, I only represented it until (5,5).

[image]

Comment: Yes your answer is correct bravo!

Comment: @Elaqqad Thanks! So in general, when I get a cartesian product of $\mathbb{A} \times \mathbb{B}$ and I get an ordered pair of the form $(c,c)$ I take the "smaller" set as a domain for $c$?

Comment: yes the smaller set in term of inclusion , if $A\subset B$ then you take $A$ if $B\subset A$ you take $B$

Comment: What if both are disjoint?

Comment: You have to take actually $A\cap B$ and if this set is empty then there will not be any element of the form $(x,x)$ in your set

Comment: @Elaqqad Oh, I see. Thank you very much! You should turn all this into an asnwer so I can vote you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove the following equality:
$$S=\left\{(x,y) \big |x\in A,\ y\in B\ \ , x=y\right\}=\{(x,x) \mid x\in A\cap B\}=S' \tag 1$$
By double inclusion:

- **First inclusion** $S\subset S'$ : let $(x,y)\in S$ then $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ so because $x=y\in B$ we have $x\in B$ then $(x,y)=(x,x)$ with $x\in A\cap B$
- **Second inclusion** $S'\subset S$ : Let $(x,x)\in S'$ then $x\in A\cap B$  so $(x,x)$ is an element of $S$ because it's an element of both $A$ and $B$;

Your assertion is an example of the assertion $(1)$ for $A=\mathbb Z$ and $B=\mathbb N$.